# Ansible Find command + copy file to a backup directory

Tags: ansible, copy, find

A small question because I struggle a little with Ansible because I do not yet master it well.
Here, I would like to search on my machines for a directory here "cells"
Once I have the list of directories containing "cells", I would like to search for the server.xml file contained in "cells"
I do the two find commands because in the searched paths there are wildcards.
If I do a find with in the path with wildcards it doesn't work.
As a result, I have the following error when I want to copy the server.xml file into my backup directory after the 2 finds:
**"msg": "'dict object' has no attribute 'files'"**

```
- name: Find
  ansible.builtin.find:
    paths: /apps
    file_type: directory
    patterns: 'cells'
    recurse: yes
  register: was_dir
 
- name: Find 
  ansible.builtin.find:
    paths: "{{ item.path }}"
    patterns: 'server.xml'
    recurse: yes
  register: was
  with_items: "{{was_dir.files}}"
 
- name: Copy
  ansible.builtin.copy:
    src: "{{ item.path }}"
    dest: "{{  backup_dir }}"
    remote_src: yes
  ignore_errors: True
  with_items: "{{was.files}}"
```

I tried to store the directories but without much success due to lack of skill.
Do you have any idea how I could proceed?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

The `was` variable is issued from a loop so its structure is different from the `was_dir` variable.

When uncertain always use the `debug` module to print and analyze the structure of a variable so that you know how to use it in future tasks.

Try with this (I didn't test it but it should work) :

```
- name: Copy
  ansible.builtin.copy:
    src: "{{ item.1.path }}"
    dest: "{{ backup_dir }}"
    remote_src: yes
  ignore_errors: True
  with_subelements:
    - "{{ was.results }}"
    - files
```